# Not getting response from youtube data api

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am new to android, I am trying to implement YouTube's search by keyword in my android app.But I am not able to get response from API (I think).I think there is some problem in search.execute().I looked some other answers too but not able to find any solution.

Here's the class (I modified it a little bit):

```
class Search {



                private static final long NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED = 2;

                /**
                 * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
                 * to make YouTube Data API requests.
                 */
                private  YouTube youtube;

                /**
                 * Initialize a YouTube object to search for videos on YouTube. Then
                 * display the name and thumbnail image of each video in the result set.
                 *
                 *
                 */
                private  void Hakuna() {
                    // Read the developer key from the properties file.


                    try {
                        // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests. The last
                        // argument is required, but since we don't need anything
                        // initialized when the HttpRequest is initialized, we override
                        // the interface and provide a no-op function.
                        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                            }
                        }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();

                        // Prompt the user to enter a query term.
                        String queryTerm = getInputQuery();

                        // Define the API request for retrieving search results.
                        YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

                        // Set your developer key from the {{ Google Cloud Console }} for
                        // non-authenticated requests. See:
                        // {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}
                        String apiKey = "HERE_I_PUT_MY_APIKEY";

                        search.setKey(apiKey);
                        search.setQ(queryTerm);

                        // Restrict the search results to only include videos. See:
                        // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type
                        search.setType("video");

                        // To increase efficiency, only retrieve the fields that the
                        // application uses.
                        search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
                        search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

                        // Call the API and print results.
                        SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
                        mResult.setText("hello");
                        List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();

                        if (searchResultList != null) {

                            prettyPrint(searchResultList.iterator(), queryTerm);

                        }
                    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                        System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                                + e.getDetails().getMessage());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                /*
                 * Prompt the user to enter a query term and return the user-specified term.
                 */
                private  String getInputQuery() throws IOException {

                    String inputQuery = "";


                    inputQuery = mSearchtext.getText().toString();

                    if (inputQuery.length() < 1) {
                        // Use the string "YouTube Developers Live" as a default.
                        inputQuery = "YouTube Developers Live";
                    }
                    return inputQuery;
                }

                /*
                 * Prints out all results in the Iterator. For each result, print the
                 * title, video ID, and thumbnail.
                 *
                 * @param iteratorSearchResults Iterator of SearchResults to print
                 *
                 * @param query Search query (String)
                 */
                private  void prettyPrint(Iterator<SearchResult> iteratorSearchResults, String query) {
                    mResult.setText("hello");
                    System.out.println("\n=============================================================");
                    System.out.println(
                            "   First " + NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED + " videos for search on \"" + query + "\".");
                    System.out.println("=============================================================\n");

                    if (!iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println(" There aren't any results for your query.");
                    }

                    while (iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {

                        SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
                        ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();

                        // Confirm that the result represents a video. Otherwise, the
                        // item will not contain a video ID.
                        if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")) {
                            Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault();

                            System.out.println(" Video Id" + rId.getVideoId());
                            System.out.println(" Title: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
                            System.out.println(" Thumbnail: " + thumbnail.getUrl());
                            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here are the dependencies that I added:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev181-1.22.0'
```

There may be some redundant lines of code, please ignore them.

Comment: what error you getting??

Comment: I am not getting any error but no response!!

Comment: So `searchResultList` is null, or empty?

Comment: Its empty i think. But i found the error (err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException) and it can be solved by using AsyncTask. Go thorugh this link - https://inducesmile.com/android-tips/android-error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception/